# Suggestions? for attribute routing? my mvc5 project ajax call only work on my local machine but not on the live site? I got 404 not found on live site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables, asp.net-ajax

[image: This is my live site]

This is the local host image [image: Image of localhost]
I got this when I check network tab

```
Request URL: https://search.ridgewater.edu/api/HutchinsonTransfer?_=1591122381716
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 134.29.168.233:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

This is my ajax call in inside DatatableJquery

```
ajax: {
       url: "../api/HutchinsonTransfer",
                dataSrc: ""

   }
```

And Below is my HutchinsonTransferController

```
namespace AttendanceReporting.Controllers.Api
{
  public class HutchinsonTransferController : ApiController
  {
    private AttendanceReportDataDbContext db = new AttendanceReportDataDbContext();

    // GET: 
    [HttpGet]

    public IHttpActionResult GetHutchinsonTransfer()
    {
        var all = from a in db.ATTENDANCE_REPORT_DATA
                  .Where(a => a.COHORT == "Transfer" && a.CAMPUS == "Hutchinson")
                  select a;
        return Ok(all.ToList());
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the URL that shows up in your network tab while on localhost (where it works)?

Comment: Request URL: https://localhost:44358/api/HutchinsonTransfer?_=1591123697243
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:44358
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Hi, Is this what you asking for?

Comment: This is my url for live site: https://search.ridgewater.edu/AttendanceReportingForm/HutchinsonTransfer

Comment: @Tommy But it is authenticated by intranet login

Comment: I just wanted to confirm your routing setup.  I would think not being logged in correctly would return a 400 error and not a 404.  I'm sorry I don't have more information / other ideas for you to assist.

Comment: just `https://search.ridgewater.edu/api/HutchinsonTransfer` return anything? for current controller `https://search.ridgewater.edu/HutchinsonTransfer` should work.

Comment: Hi @Sajid I tried both of the url you gave, both gave me 404

Comment: Hi @Saranya have you debug in the Js file?

Comment: @Sajid no, It works on the localhost, so I didn't debug my js file